# How to fit image in circular border and rectangular border

Tags: android, xml

By using xml files drawn circle and rectangle shapes here is code
rectangle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<size
    android:height="120dp"
    android:width="180dp" />

<corners android:radius="30px" />

<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
```

and here is my circle.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

   <solid 
       android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>

   <size 
       android:width="120dp"
        android:height="120dp"/>

    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
</shape>
```

now arranged these drawable as background for imageview then able to see image background with respective shape but if i place image in imageview then image is out of circle or rectangle how to make image with in border.(Sorry for grammar mistakes)